# What's the best way to modularise reusable functionality across Flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, authentication, design-patterns, interface, architecture

*TLDR: When following clean architecture, when should a reusable piece of functionality be reused across different apps via a **module** vs a **template**, and how does one decide on the **interface** of a module?*

### Background

I'm currently writing some packages (for personal use when freelancing) for common functionality that can be reused across multiple Flutter apps and wondering what's a good way to organise them. With my apps I follow the clean architecture guidelines, splitting an app by features, with each feature consisting of data, domain and presentation layers:

```
|--> lib/
      |
      |--> feature_a/
      |       |
      |       |--> data/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> data_sources/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> repository_implementations/
      |       |      |
      |       |--> domain/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> repository_contracts/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> entities/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> use_cases/
      |       |      |
      |       |--> presentation/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> blocs/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> screens/
      |       |      |
      |       |      |--> widgets/
      |       |      |
      |--> feature_b
      |       |
      |       |--> ...
```

### Example

If we take the **user authentication** feature, for example, I know that:

- The entire domain layer, as well as the bloc, will be the **same** across most apps (email and password validation, authentication/login blocs, etc.)
- The data layer will **change** depending on the backend/database (different providers = different calls)
- The screens/widgets will **change** with different UI's (different apps will have different login and onboarding pages)

### Current Approach

My thinking is to write something like a single backend-agnostic "core_auth_kit" package, which contains the domain and bloc, and one package for each backend service I might use, e.g. "firebase_auth_kit", "mongodb_auth_kit", etc. Each backend-specific package will use the "core_auth_kit" as the outward-facing interface.

Here's how I plan on using this. If I'm writing a simple Firebase Flutter app, I will simply import the "firebase_auth_kit" package, and instantiate its auth_bloc at the root of the app inside a MultiBlocProvider, showing the login page if the state is "unauthenticated" and the home page if it's "authenticated".
[image: diagram of package structure]

### Questions

1. What is the standard practice for deciding on the boundary of a module? i.e. is this approach of using the "highest common layer" (bloc in the authentication example) the way to go?
2. When should a reusable piece of functionality be extracted as a template vs a module (is my example a good candidate for a module, or should it be a template instead)?